# Making webpack throw errors for unknown imports instead of warnings

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, javascript-import

Webpack very conveniently shows warnings when it finds imports which it believes do not exist:

```
WARNING in ./somefile.js 18:34-55 "export 'A_CONSTANT' was not
found in './constants.js'
```

This is great, but it would be even better to be able to receive an actual error, ideally one that will show up in the webpack dev server `overlay` option. Is there a way to do this